# unistall-package on remote computer

Tags: powershell

i want to uninstall a software on a remote computer. i can fetch the installed software.
now i want to copy the name of the software und paste it to my uninstall command but it doens't work. my script tries to start all installed software.

what is wrong in my script?
is it even possible to get an output of the installed software as a enumeration and i just need to enter the number?

```
Function Get-Package {Get-Package -Provider Programs -IncludeWindowsInstaller}

$pcname = read-host "give pc name"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pcname `
-ScriptBlock ${Function:Get-Package} 
write-host
write-host
$software = read-host "give software name"
function Uninstall-Package {get-Package -Name "$software" | Uninstall-Package}
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pcname `
-ScriptBlock ${Function:uninstall-Package}
```

Comment: Can you confirm that `$software` holds the input value?

Comment: and yes, you can make a choice selection out of them and I will post it as an answer but, don't mark it as an answer. Just want you to see how its done as it would come out pretty ugly pasted here.

Comment: how can i test it?

Comment: highlight $software and run the selection, or just type $software in your console

Comment: yes $software holds my input. if i type for example "testsoftware" and run the highlighted $software it outputs my "testsoftware"

Answer (score 0):

Creating a choice selection using the `for` loop.

```
$SofNames = Get-Package -ProviderName programs -IncludeWindowsInstaller | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
    for($i=0; $i -lt $SofNames.count;$i++){
        "$($i): $($SofNames[$i])"}

$iN = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Number"
$SofNames[$iN]
```

You're basically iterating through the returned values for `$SofNames`, and outputting it with its corresponding index number.

So, when you run the choice selection with the variable `$iN`, that itself becomes the index number you selected. Now you're able to select the corresponding name from the list of names in `$SofNames`, just like you would a regular array, `$SofNames[$iN]`.

Comment: Give me a few to get to work and will help you out with your actual problem!

Answer (score 0):

@Abraham Zinala
your enumeration works fine but i still have the problem that my script tries to uninstall all software, not that one what i marked

```
######get actuall installed software
Function Get-Package {
$SofNames = Get-Package -ProviderName programs -IncludeWindowsInstaller | Select-  Object -ExpandProperty Name | sort-object
for($i=0; $i -lt $SofNames.count;$i++){
    "$($i): $($SofNames[$i])"}
}

#####fetch software on remote machine
$pcname = read-host "Gebe den PC Namen/IP Adresse ein"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pcname `
    -ScriptBlock ${Function:Get-Package}


#####uninstall software on remote machine
$iN = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Number"
function Uninstall-Package {get-Package -Name $iN | Uninstall-Package}
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pcname `
    -ScriptBlock ${Function:uninstall-Package}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im back! Okay, so more than likely, you're variables arent being expanded inside the your function you're trying to invoke.

Give this a shot:

```
#####fetch software on remote machine
$pcname = read-host "Gebe den PC Namen/IP Adresse ein"
$SofNames = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pcname -ScriptBlock {
    Get-Package -ProviderName programs -IncludeWindowsInstaller | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | sort-object}

for($i=0; $i -lt $SofNames.count;$i++){
    "$($i): $($SofNames[$i])"}

$iN = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Number"
$iNi = $SofNames[$iN]

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pcname -ScriptBlock { Uninstall-Package -Name "$iNi" }
```

Theres really no need for you to run `Get-Package` again when you can just run the uninstall cmdlet directly. Im assuming since its not passing over the value, its just piping all the results of `Get-Package` over to `Uninstall-Package`, hence why it tried to uninstall everything. We can avoid that by just using `Uninstall-Package` without having a value piped to it.

Comment: Hi Abraham, unfortunately it doesn't work. "The argument cannot be bound to the name parameter because it is an empty string."

Comment: You may have to look at the syntax for `Uninstall-Package`, I did that off top of my head so i may be missing a parameter.